# Flutter , keeping container of a ListView on the top of the screen when scrolling down

Tags: flutter

how to keep a specific container of a ListView on the top of the screen when scrolling down?

for example:

---

appBar

---

image1(inside the listview)

---

tabs(should stay below appBar but image1 disappears when scrolling down)

---

list item 1

---

list item 2
....

---

navBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to work with `SliverList` and `SliverAppBar` to achieve a layout like that.

Read more about it in this [article](https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f).